# show daily Sentence by php and get from database

Tags: php, database

how i can show daily Sentence in site by get Non-recurring value from database ?

my database have more than 365 Sentence

my database table's Structure is :

`id,text`

i think i should crate a `show` in my table's Structure that Default value is `0` and when Sentence showed in site `show = 1`

this is true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add an extra column and get record using query like this:

```
select text from sentences where show=0;
```

**EDIT:**

You can get random record from table as well.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM `sentences` WHERE show=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

*But this method is slow with large tables. See more details in following article:*

- [SQL to Select a random row from a database table](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm)

Comment: i understand this but how i can get record random ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also reduce the number of sentences in your database to 366 and run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id = DAYOFYEAR(NOW())
```

Of course, this means you need to keep 366 sentences with ID numbers 1-366, else it won't work.

Comment: this is better because if i use top method in new year my source don't work because all of sentence' `show=1` and don't show anymore 

thanks a lot mingos

Answer (score 0):

either yes (create that show column) or just show them in sequence, today is day 1, show sentence id 1, tomorrow sentence 2 etc.